# Find out specifics about auto-released DCOM client

Tags: delphi, client-server, delphi-10-seattle, dcom

I have made a DCOM server to which several clients can connect.

If I understand correctly, if a client for some reason becomes inactive (crashes, loses connection), the DCOM will automatically release it after three missed pings. Is there some way to find out specifics, such as which client it was that was released? So that I can for example remove them from a list of active users.

I added a  `_Release` function to check that crashed clients are being released as they should (they are, but `_Release` is called twice for some reason...) but that is about as far as I have come. I am quite new to this.

Please let me know if there is any necessary information I should include. Any help or pointers in a helpful direction would be much appreciated!